# python - replace some values in a specific column from csv using a criteria (Kelvin to Celsius)

Tags: python, csv, replace, conditional-statements, criteria

In the same column we have temperature data in Kelvin and Celsius. How can I make a new column in which I have the same type of date (Kelvin or Celsius). I have a lot of data in csv format.
I tried to use something like: if initial_temperature > 50 write new_temperature = initial_temperature – 273.15, where I supposed that we cannot have a temperature in Celsius higher than 50.

```
Input_data =[37, 309.15, 38, 310.5]
Output_data = [37, 36, 38, 37.35]
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you clarify it a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your data in csv file in one column like this:

input_data.csv

```
37
309.15
38
310.5
```

Then you can just read this data row by row from file and save it to another file with additional column.

```
import csv

with open('input_data.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    output_file = open('output_data.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    for row in reader:
        row_values = []
        if float(row[0]) > 50:
            row_values.append(float(row[0]))  # Column A
            row_values.append(round(float(row[0]) - 273.15, 2))  # Column B
            writer.writerow(row_values)
        else:
            row_values.append(float(row[0]))  # Column A
            row_values.append(float(row[0]))  # Column B
            writer.writerow(row_values)
    output_file.close()
```

Output in another file:

output_data.csv

```
37.0,37.0
309.15,36.0
38.0,38.0
310.5,37.35
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just list of values, you could use list comprehension to get the result:

```py
>>> Input_data =[37, 309.15, 38, 310.5]
>>> Output_data = [round((x - 273.15),2) if x > 50 else x for x in Input_data]
>>> Output_data
[37, 36.0, 38, 37.35]
```

Since you've mentioned columns, I suppose you have some kind of data frame. For pandas data frame you can use lambda function:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Input_data':[37, 309.15, 38, 310.5]})
>>> df
   Input_data
0       37.00
1      309.15
2       38.00
3      310.50
>>> df['Output_data'] = df['Input_data'].apply(lambda x: x - 273.15 if x > 50 else x)
>>> df
   Input_data  Output_data
0       37.00        37.00
1      309.15        36.00
2       38.00        38.00
3      310.50        37.35
```

For numpy arrays it is like this:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([37, 309.15, 38, 310.5])
>>> x
array([ 37.  , 309.15,  38.  , 310.5 ])
>>>
>>> y = np.where(x > 50, x - 273.15, x)
>>> y
array([37.  , 36.  , 38.  , 37.35])
```